# Why delete keyword not deleting the variable with var keyword

Tags: javascript

I have two statements.

```
 var myVar = "krijesh";
 delete myVar;

 myAnothervar = "pv";
 delete myAnothervar;
```

Here first statement gives you the output false and second output gives you the output true. Why ?

Comment: Good explanation http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> The `delete` operator removes a property from an object.
>
> `delete` is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names.
>
> While sometimes mis-characterized as global variables, assignments that don't specify an object (e.g. x = 5) are actually property assignments on the global object.

In other words, the `delete` operator only deletes object properties, not variables.

`var x = y` declares a local variable named `x`. `x = y` declares a property `x` on the global object.

Answer (score 2):

The delete keyword deletes a property from an object. It does not "delete" the existence of a variable. Here is a proper usage of delete.

```
var myObject = { count: 100, name: 'KriZ' }

// { count: 100, name: 'KriZ' }

delete myObject.name;

// { count: 100 }
```